# How to pass json output to label in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pass the json output to label, but i couldnt get the string of the json, how to get the name in view controller?
The output, i will only get 1 record

```
var results = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadSites()
    //self.labelName.text = results["name"].string!

}


func loadSites(){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://exapmle.com/api")
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

            if(json != nil){
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)

                println(jsonObj)

            }

    }
}
```

JSON Output

```
{
    "status" : "success",
    "result" : [{"name" : "Example"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonResult = JSON(json!)

self.labelName.text = jsonResult["result"][0]["name"].string!
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the UI in the main thread. This is why I updated my `label.text` inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{})`.

```
func loadSites(){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://exapmle.com/api")
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

            if(json != nil) {
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                println(jsonObj)

                if let name = jsonObj["result"][0]["name"].string {

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.label.text = name
                    })

                }
            }
    }
}
```